# rails test email validation error due to password testing?

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

Following the newest version of Michael Hartl's rails guide

I have the following test file in my test/models/user_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

def setup
    # prevously.
    #@user = User.new(name: "Example Name", email: "example@example.com")
    # password and password_conformation is added after has_secure_password is implemented in User.rb
    @user = User.new(name: "Example Name", email: "example@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
end

.... # other tests

# should be a valid user
test "should be valid" do 
    assert @user.valid?
end

# test for valid email addresses
test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                         first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
end

#test for invalid email addresses
test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                           foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
end

# PROBLEM STARTS HERE !!!!
# test password minimum length as 8
test "password should have a minimum length" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 7
    assert_not @user.valid?
end

..... # more other tests


end
```

For some reason it's returning the following when I run bundle exec rake test

```
  1) Failure:
UserTest#test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses [/Users/jackCHH/Desktop/Websites/cloudSolar/test/models/user_test.rb:49]:
"user@example.com" should be valid


  2) Failure:
UserTest#test_should_be_valid [/Users/jackCHH/Desktop/Websites/cloudSolar/test/models/user_test.rb:14]:
Failed assertion, no message given.
```

The problem started after I added the test script to test the password's length. I also added **validates :password, length: { minimum: 8 }** to my model User.rb. If I remove the validation line in my model and the password_length test script, the test passes again.

My email declaration for @user seems correct (example@example.com), so I am not sure why it's an invalid email now

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

In my declaration of @user, both my password and password_confirmation are foobar, which is only length 6. I set it so that the requirement is 8 characters minimum, therefore it returns an error.

After changing the password to thisfoobar, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue but had

> attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

in the user.rb file, once I removed this line everything worked without error.